# Is there is any matrix $C$ such that which satisfied $AC= \mathbb{I}_{3\times3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Is  there is any  matrix $C$ such that which  satisfied  $AC= \mathbb{I}_{3\times3}$ where  $$A = \begin{bmatrix}  2&3 \\ 1& 2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

I was thinking many times , but  i could not get its

Any hints\ solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Tip: To get the identity matrix, you have to solve for certain equations, with some of them equating a number and others another number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $C$ must be of form: $$C = \begin{bmatrix}  a&c&e \\ 
                       b& d&f
\end{bmatrix}$$

So we have $2a+3b=1$ , $a+2b = 0$ and $a+b=0$. But from last two you get $a=b=0$ so there is no $C$.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of $A$ as a linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Because of the dimensions it cannot be surjective.

If there was a matrix $C$ such that $AC=I$ then we have
$$A(C(x))=x$$
for every $x$, in particular the equation $A(y)=x$ is always solvable. But this is impossible since $A$ is not surjective.

Alternatively you could use brute force, write
$$C=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\ d & e & f 
\end{pmatrix}$$
and write down all the equations given by $AC=I$. You can show they have no solutions. The above method works in higher dimensions as well, as long as $A$ as more lines than columns.